# NSUserdefaults lost its memory

Tags: swift3, nsuserdefaults

I am using Swift 3 and facebook login, and save some basic values i get from the facebookSDKGraphrequest in user defaults like this:

```
        // save basic settings in standard user defaults: age, gender, first name
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(firstName!, forKey: "firstName")
        defaults.set(gender!, forKey: "gender")

        let currentUserAge = calculateAge(birthday: birthDay!)
        defaults.set(currentUserAge, forKey: "age")
```

I only need to run that code once when the user logs in, then I save the info into userDefaults, and I'm set.

so the issue i Have is that recently, the last few times I build and open my app on the phone, my userDefaults was empty.

when I run this code in another class,

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
var name = defaults.object(forKey: "firstName") as? String
var age = defaults.integer(forKey: "age")
var gender = defaults.object(forKey: "gender") as? String
```

I was getting nil for all those values. So now I'm paranoid because if this happens in a user's app, it will crash.

Can someone explain why UserDefaults would lose its memory?
I did nothing to delete or reset the values. I went through probably 100 builds and this last time, UserDefaults' values were nil.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` does not store immediately its content to disk. `synchronize` method is called periodically to write data to disk. It seems it is not called in your case. Try call `defaults.synchronize` when you have finished setting up your values.

(source : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

Comment: that doesn't explain why UserDefaults would lose its data  though, after It has already sychronized perfectly fine? Possibly what happened is that my facebook request failed, the values I got were nil, and I set the default to nil in my code.

Comment: You're right, the data saved on the disk should not disappear if a missing call to `synchronize` was the issue.